# Retain Event handler assignments when cutting and pasting WinForms controls in VS2012 C# project?

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to maintain the Event handler assignments when cutting and pasting controls in the VS2012 designer?  For example, I have a graph control that has a Load event with code in the Event stub.  If I cut and paste the graph control, the Load event no longer shows as having an Event handler assignment in the Properties Editor.  I have to use the drop-down box next to the Load event to reselect my existing Event handler code for the Load event (redo the assignment).  Is there a way to cut and paste controls without losing the Event handler assignments?

In Delphi I could just cut and paste controls freely and the event handler assignments were part of the clipboard text so they were retained when a control was pasted onto a form or frame. I am hoping there is a way to do the same with Visual Studio 2012 and a C# project.

Comment: Something strange about this question.  You'd only cut+paste to move it to an entirely different form.  Which will only have the appropriate event handler by rare accident.  It sounds like you are just using it wrong, drag the control instead.

Comment: @HansPassant - A frequent use case is when I decide to move several large controls to various tabs on a tabbed (pages) control.  I find it awkward to have to reset the Dock property settings and try to drag and drop everything properly.  At least for me, dropping the tabbed control onto the form and then cutting and pasting the needed controls onto the different pages (tabs) is much easier.  If VS doesn't work that way then I get that, but I was hoping there was a way to do what I want to.

Comment: Another use case is when you want to move some of the controls from the WinForm to new UserControl (during refactoring). If you just cut&paste it, then you have to create the event handlers again (and copy the code for it...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you cut or copy a control using the Visual Studio designer only the properties of the controls are copied. This is by design and in my opinion, is justified. It would be counter intuitive most of the time if you where copying a control and all of the same event handlers where assigned or copied over.

It sounds like the control is remaining in the same Form. In which case dragging and placing the control should suffice for the most part.

Comment: Consider for example this scenario: I have a SplitContainer in my form that has its Dock property set to "Fill". It contains several child controls, many of which have event handlers attached to them. Later I decide to put a StatusStrip at the bottom of my form. Guess what, you can't set it to dock to the bottom of your form. The SplitContainer will continue to use the Fill the the StatusStrip (though apparently docked to the bottom) will actually be hiding some part of the SplitContainer. The only around it is to CUT the SplitContainer and then PASTE it back.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the Document Outline

```
View > Other Windows > Document Outline
```

And find your desired control and then drag and drop it to target container.
In this case you wont miss any events.

Answer (score 1):

One way to reassign the events is as the following:

- Double click on the pasted controls, it creates an event with a name like:

  ```
  button1_Click_1(...)
  ```
- Now change the function name to the original name `button1_Click`, the IDE shows a warning about the duplication of functions, click OK and then remove the function you already created.